# select from mulitple values using ANY in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am running a query on Postgres table as below:

```
      Column      |            Type             |     Modifiers
------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------
 status           | character varying(16)  

select FROM incoming_requests WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(status), '') IN ('','OK','ERROR');
```

This seems to working fine but below not

```
select FROM incoming_requests WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(status), '') = ANY ('','OK','ERROR');

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...quests WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(status), '') = ANY (" ","OK","ERR...

select FROM incoming_requests WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(status), '') = ANY (" ","OK","ERROR");
```

Also suggest if there is any difference in performance using `ANY` or `IN`

Comment: You are missing single quotes around `ERROR` in the second query.

Comment: the IN Clause has also a missing single quote

Comment: Yeah.. sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no difference

> ```
> CREATE TABLE incoming_requests ("status" character varying(16) )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select FROM incoming_requests WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(status), '') = ANY (array['', 'OK', 'ERROR']);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3c015e813da15cecc5caa2f74e52c552)*